# how to get number of connections from rabbitmq start until rabbitmq server stop

Tags: rabbitmq

I can get number of current connections by counting elements in /api/connections, and If I want number of all connections from rabbitmq server start, what should I do?, please give me some suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get any retrospective statistics data from RabbitMQ even with Management API (at least out of the box).

As a workaround, you can collect such data with the help of [`rabbitmq_event_exchange`](https://github.com/simonmacmullen/rabbitmq-event-exchange) [Community Plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/community-plugins.html) and then process events on application level.

Comment: awesome! that's really help me, Is there a node.js module?

Comment: Yeah, sure, just google it (i'm not a nodejs guy, but there are a lot of questions about nodejs+amqp which utilizes some libs). P.S. if you are asking about `rabbitmq_event_exchange`-specific module - i have no idea and probably not, while `rabbitmq_event_exchange` is broker-level plugin which simply add exchange and publish messages to it. This plugin doesn't extend AMQP protocol, so you can use it with plain amqp library.